# How to write own dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

This have been asked in the interview.

How to write own dynamic_cast. I think, on the basis of typeid's name function.

Now how to implement own typid? I have no clue on it.

Comment: @saurabh01 Go back through questions that you've asked and pick the answer that was most helpful (if any). Click on the checkbox to the left of that answer to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely a contender for crappiest interview question of the month.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I agree. There's a reason that DC is implemented by the compiler.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: what's crappy about figuring out what the compiler (conceivably) does? It's better than thinking it works by magic.

Comment: @Ammon The compiler doesn't do anything you can implement yourself. A question such as "How might a compiler implement dynamic_cast?" would be better, but still really only of interest to C++ compiler implementers. A good question would be something like "When would you use dynamic_cast?"

Comment: I don't (yet) believe that it is possible in general. Even if you work out that two types are related there are casts that `dynamic_cast` can perform that can't be done any other way, e.g. from a virtual base class or between sibling base classes of a multiple inheritance tree.

Comment: @Saurabh01: Now that you have been here for the quarter of a year, don't you think that it might be a good idea to finally take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and finally learn how this place works? The reason why you usually get surprisingly good answers within minutes of asking is that everyone participates in making this a good place to hang out and ask and answer questions. Do your share (it's small) or get ignored.

Comment: I've actually done this............ to have a cross-dll-safe and cross-compiler-safe implementation.

Comment: I believe the right answer is that **you don't**. Something that would fully respect the contract of `dynamic_cast` smells like UB and doing that is rather a reason for firing than for hiring.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a reason you don't have any clue, `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` are not like `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`, they actually perform pointer arithmetic and are somewhat typesafe.

**The pointer arithmetic**

In order to illustrate this, think of the following design:

```
struct Base1 { virtual ~Base1(); char a; };
struct Base2 { virtual ~Base2(); char b; };

struct Derived: Base1, Base2 {};
```

An instance of `Derived` should look something like this (it's based on gcc since it is actually compiler dependent...):

```
|      Cell 1       | Cell 2 |      Cell 3        | Cell 4 |
| vtable pointer    |    a   | vtable pointer     |    b   |
|         Base 1             |        Base 2               |
|                     Derived                              |
```

Now think of the work necessary for casting:

- casting from `Derived` to `Base1` does not require any extra work, they are at the same physical address
- casting from `Derived` to `Base2` necessitates to shift the pointer by 2 bytes

Therefore, it is necessary to know the memory layout of the objects to be able to cast between one derived object and one of its base. And this is only known to the compiler, the information is not accessible through any API, it's not standardised or anything else.

In code, this would translate like:

```
Derived derived;
Base2* b2 = reinterpret_cast<Base2>(((char*)&derived) + 2);
```

And that is, of course, for a `static_cast`.

Now, if you were able to use `static_cast` in the implementation of `dynamic_cast`, then you could leverage the compiler and let it handle the pointer arithmetic for you... but you're still not out of the wood.

**Writing dynamic_cast ?**

First things first, we need to clarify the specifications of `dynamic_cast`:

- `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&base);` returns null if `base` is not an instance of `Derived`.
- `dynamic_cast<Derived&>(base);` throws `std::bad_cast` in this case.
- `dynamic_cast<void*>(base);` returns the address of the most derived class
- `dynamic_cast` respect the access specifications (`public`, `protected` and `private` inheritance)

I don't know about you, but I think it's going to be ugly. Using `typeid` is not sufficient here:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(); };
struct Intermediate: Base {};
struct Derived: Base {};

void func()
{
  Derived derived;
  Base& base = derived;
  Intermediate& inter = dynamic_cast<Intermediate&>(base); // arg
}
```

The issue here is that `typeid(base) == typeid(Derived) != typeid(Intermediate)`, so you can't rely on that either.

Another amusing thing:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(); };
struct Derived: virtual Base {};

void func(Base& base)
{
  Derived& derived = static_cast<Derived&>(base); // Fails
}
```

`static_cast` doesn't work when virtual inheritance is involved... so we've go a problem of pointer arithmetic computation creeping in.

**An almost solution**

```
class Object
{
public:
  Object(): mMostDerived(0) {}
  virtual ~Object() {}

  void* GetMostDerived() const { return mMostDerived; }

  template <class T>
  T* dynamiccast()
  {
    Object const& me = *this;
    return const_cast<T*>(me.dynamiccast());
  }

  template <class T>
  T const* dynamiccast() const
  {
    char const* name = typeid(T).name();
    derived_t::const_iterator it = mDeriveds.find(name);
    if (it == mDeriveds.end()) { return 0; }
    else { return reinterpret_cast<T const*>(it->second); }
  }

protected:
  template <class T>
  void add(T* t)
  {
    void* address = t;
    mDerived[typeid(t).name()] = address;
    if (mMostDerived == 0 || mMostDerived > address) { mMostDerived= address; }
  }

private:
  typedef std::map < char const*, void* > derived_t;
  void* mMostDerived;
  derived_t mDeriveds;
};

// Purposely no doing anything to help swapping...

template <class T>
T* dynamiccast(Object* o) { return o ? o->dynamiccast<T>() : 0; }

template <class T>
T const* dynamiccast(Object const* o) { return o ? o->dynamiccast<T>() : 0; }

template <class T>
T& dynamiccast(Object& o)
{
  if (T* t = o.dynamiccast<T>()) { return t; }
  else { throw std::bad_cast(); }
}

template <class T>
T const& dynamiccast(Object const& o)
{
  if (T const* t = o.dynamiccast<T>()) { return t; }
  else { throw std::bad_cast(); }
}
```

You need some little things in the constructor:

```
class Base: public Object
{
public:
  Base() { this->add(this); }
};
```

So, let's check:

- classic uses: okay
- `virtual` inheritance ? it should work... but not tested
- respecting access specifiers... ARG :/

Good luck to anyone trying to implement this outside of the compiler, really :x

Comment: In your graphical depiction of the class layout at the top, please change 'Byte' to something else because the vtable-pointer is [almost definitely] not a Byte.

Comment: @iAdjunct: Indeed, I used `Cell` instead.

Answer (score 1):

ONe way is to declare a static identifier (an integer for example) which defines the class ID. In the class you could implement both static and scoped routines wich returns the class identifier (*Remeber to mark routines virtual*).

The static identifier shall be initialized at application initialization. One way is to call an InitializeId routine for each class, but this mean that the class names must be known, and the initialization code shall be modified each time the class hierarchy is modified. Another way is to check for valid identifier at construction time, but this introduces an overhead since each time a class is constructed the check is executed, but only the first time is usefull (additionally if no class is constructed, the static routine cannot be usefull since the identifier is never initialized).

A fair implementation could be a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class ClassId<T>
{
    public:

    static int GetClassId() { return (sClassId); }

    virtual int GetClassId() const { return (sClassId); }

    template<typename U> static void StateDerivation() {
        gClassMap[ClassId<T>::GetClassId()].push_back(ClassId<U>::GetClassId());
    }

    template<typename U> const U DynamicCast() const {
        std::map<int, std::list<int>>::const_iterator it = gClassMap.find(ClassId<T>); // Base class type, with relative derivations declared with StateDerivation()
        int id = ClassId<U>::GetClassId();

        if (id == ClassId<T>::GetClassId()) return (static_cast<U>(this));

        while (it != gClassMap.end()) {
            for (std::list<int>::const_iterator = pit->second.begin(), pite = it->second->end(); pit != pite; pit++) {
                if ((*pit) == id) return (static_cast<U>(this));
                // ... For each derived element, iterate over the stated derivations.
                // Easy to implement with a recursive function, better if using a std::stack to avoid recursion.
            }
        }

        return (null); 
    }  

    private:

    static int sClassId;
}

#define CLASS_IMP(klass) static int ClassId<klass>::sClassId = gClassId++;

// Global scope variables    

static int gClassId = 0;
static std::map<int, std::list<int>> gClassMap;
```

CLASS_IMP shall be defined in for each class deriving from ClassId, and gClassId and gClassMap shall be visible at global scope.

The available class identifiers are keeped by a single static integer variable accessible by all classes (a base class ClassID or a global variable), which is incremented each time a new class identifier is assigned.

To represents the class hierarchy is sufficient a map between the class identifier and its derived classes. To know whether any class can be casted to a specific class, iterate over the map and check declare derivations.

There are many difficulties to face... use of references! virtual derivations! bad casting! Bad class type mapping initialization will lead to casting errors...

---

Relationships between classes shall be defined manually, hardcoded with the initialization routine. This allow to determine whether a class derived from, or whether two classes as a common derivation.

```
class Base : ClassId<Base> {  }
#define CLASS_IMP(Base);
class Derived : public Base, public ClassId<Derived> {  }
#define CLASS_IMP(Derived);
class DerivedDerived : public Derived, public ClassId<DerivedDerived> {  }
#define CLASS_IMP(DerivedDerived);

static void DeclareDerivations()
{
    ClassId<Base>::StateDerivation<Derived>();
    ClassId<Derived>::StateDerivation<DerivedDerived>();
}
```

---

Personally I agree with "there is a reason if compilers implements dynamic_cast"; probably the compiler do the things better (especially with respect of the example code!).

Comment: Suppose you've discovered that you have references to classes that appear in the same hierarchy, how are you proposing to actually do the `dynamic_cast` ?

Comment: Updated. I think it was obvious the solution path.

Comment: You seem to be using a `reinterpret_cast` of a `ClassId` specialization as the result of `DynamicCast`. Surely this is the wrong class to be casting; even if it was the right class reinterpret_cast isn't going to do the appropriate adjustments for MI hierarchies. Have I missed something obvious in your solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly highlighted the problem that I meant. `static_cast` isn't correct either. Consider `struct A { virtual ~A(); }; struct B : virtual A {}; struct C : virtual A {}; struct D : B, C {};` Even though `B` and `C` might be pointers to sub-objects of the same `D` instance, a `static_cast` between them is not valid and a `reinterpret_cast` is extremely unlikely to yield the correct results. Only `dynamic_cast` is guaranteed to yield the correct results but this is what we are trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

To attempt an answer slightly less routine, if slightly less defined:

What you need to do is cast the pointer to an int*, create a new type T on the stack, cast a pointer to it to int*, and compare the first int in both types. This will do a vtable address comparison. If they are the same type, they will have the same vtable. Else, they don't.

The more sensible of us just stick an integral constant in our classes.

Comment: But this doesn't tell you if it's possible to `dynamic_cast` between two types or how to perform the cast.

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Derive all objects from some typeid interface with a virtual function WhoAmI().
Override it in all deriving classes.